# FULL Outer join Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the below data set from different table

```
Table1
-------
EMPID    DEPID   C1  C2  SUM
---------------------------
100      200     2    3   111
100      200     4    4   222

 Table2
-------
EMPID    DEPID   C1  C2  SUM
---------------------------
100      200     4    4   333
100      200     5    6   444
```

Result I am looking for ---

```
Table1
-------
EMPID    DEPID   T1.C1  T1.C2  T2.C1   T2.C2    T1.SUM   T2.SUM
--------------------------------------------------------------
100      200       2      3     NULL    NULL     111      NULL
100      200       4      4      4        4      222      333
100      200       NULL   NULL   5        6      NULL     444
```

Any help is much appriciated. I used Full Outer Join but could not achive this.

Comment: what version of oracle?

Comment: Which columns should the joins be on? `t1.c1 = t2.c1`? `t1.c2 = t2.c2`? Both of them? Or `t1.c1 = t2.c2`? `t2.c1 = t1.c2`? Or these both?

Comment: The join condition is T1.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID and T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_id and T1.C1 = T2.C1 and T1.C2 = T2.C2 .. SO I am checking for the above four conditions and if C1 and C2 matches I am printing the SUM from both the tables otherwise the corresponding coulmns will be NULL.

Comment: @MAltaf You haven't shown what results you want when `empid` or `depid` are missing.

Comment: I am looking for a INNER JOIN for T1.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID and T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_ID and a OUTER JOIN for T1.C1 = T2.C1 and T1.C2 = T2.C2 .... So i need only thse records for which T1.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID and T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_ID always satisfy. EMPID and DEPTID will always be there in T1 and T2..

Answer (score 3):

You want an `INNER JOIN` on `(emp_id, dep_id)` with a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on `(c1, c2)`. I think you won't be able to write this join condition in a single step. I propose a two-step query (a `FULL OUTER JOIN` followed by a filter subquery).

```
SQL> WITH t1 AS (
  2  SELECT 100 emp_id, 200 dep_id, 2 c1, 3 c2, 111 sum FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 100 emp_id, 200 dep_id, 4 c1, 4 c2, 222 sum FROM dual
  4  ), t2 AS (
  5  SELECT 100 emp_id, 200 dep_id, 4 c1, 4 c2, 333 sum FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 100 emp_id, 200 dep_id, 5 c1, 6 c2, 444 sum FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 100 emp_id, 300 dep_id, 7 c1, 8 c2, 555 sum FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT COALESCE(t1.emp_id, t2.emp_id) emp_id,
 10         COALESCE(t1.dep_id, t2.dep_id) dep_id,
 11         t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c1, t2.c2, t1.sum, t2.sum
 12    FROM t1
 13    FULL OUTER JOIN t2
 14      ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
 15     AND t1.dep_id = t2.dep_id
 16     AND t1.c1 = t2.c1
 17     AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
 18   WHERE (COALESCE(t1.emp_id, t2.emp_id), COALESCE(t1.dep_id, t2.dep_id))
 19         IN (SELECT t1.emp_id, t1.dep_id
 20               FROM t1
 21               JOIN t2 ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
 22                      AND t1.dep_id = t2.dep_id)
 23  ORDER BY t1.c1;

    EMP_ID     DEP_ID         C1         C2         C1         C2  SUM  SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----
       100        200          2          3                        111 
       100        200          4          4          4          4  222  333
       100        200                                5          6       444
```

Note that I added a row in `T2` from your example to demonstrate the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Vincent....But the join condition is T1.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID and T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_id and T1.C1 = T2.C1 and T1.C2 = T2.C2 .. SO I am checking for the above four conditions and if C1 and C2 matches I am printing the SUM from both the tables otherwise the corresponding coulmns will be NULL.

Comment: That's exactly the join condition I have written, don't you agree?

Comment: My applogies for the confusion.. I have to make sure that T1.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID and T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_ID always works.. here the full outer join will give all the records even if there is no record for emp_id and dept_id in one of the table.

Comment: Summarizing I am looking for a INNER JOIN for T1.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID and T1.DEP_ID = T2.DEP_ID and a OUTER JOIN for T1.C1 = T2.C1 and T1.C2 = T2.C2

Comment: Your example data didn't cover all cases then =) See my updated answer.